# Realtime search against only 1 column in Mysql - without any plugins

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

However I found some threads about this, but nothing fits to my case.

I have a search field in my mobile app, where after text change, the real time search is running via calling my API.

The search request starts only if there are 3 or more characters entered and is searching ONLY in 1 DB column, called TITLE. So each time the user enters a letter, a query is searching for it.

Currently I have it like this (I know this solution is very bad). $searchedword is the word user entered:

```
if (!empty($searchedword)&&strlen($searchedword)>2 ) {$searchedword=strtolower($searchedword);

$sql = "SELECT  * FROM TABLE ";$result = $mysqli->query($sql); $output='';
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($data=$result->fetch_array()) {
      $title=strtolower($data['title']);$content=$data['content'];
if (strpos($title,$searchedword) !== false ) {$output.=$title.','.$content;}
}}
```

So this just checks, if the title from DB contains the searched word. This works very well, but I think it is very bad according to performance, because each time the user enters a letter to the search field, each time all the data from the table are queried and looked for that word.

I want to recreate my code to meet the best performance.

So my first question is, should I add a FULLTEXT INDEX to the TITLE column in DB, will it help or will it just increase the disk space? As I am just searching against 1 column and in this column is just a title (1 or 2 words max).

And second question, what should be the best query for my case and of course with the best performance? As I need to search after each letter which user enters.

Can I use the search this way?

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$searchedword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

However it seems, this will return only if the word completely matches the title, but returns nothing when the word is part of the title, so it is not a good solution.

The only solution which works is this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE title LIKE '%$searchedword%'  "
```

but what about performance? And I don't understand how this works, because searchedword are converted to lowercase and I have removed the accents from that word, and the TITLE column in DB has accents and also Uppercase, but this search works very well!

Comment: that is not my full code, but thank you for this information, I will study something about this. I didn't know escaping is not enough, was using this from the beginning: $str = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($str)));$str = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$str);

Comment: What you are doing is mutilating your strings and escaping. While it could cover you in 99% of the case it is a messy and dangerous solution. It is much easier to simply separate your data from SQL and use parameter binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `title` column has a collation like `utfmb4_general_ci`, you don't have to worry about dealing with upper case, lower case, and diacritical marks in your MySQL `WHERE` clauses. MySQL will do it for you. It is *really* good at handling [character sets and collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html) in all kinds of languages.  (Such things are very helpful to Swedish-language users, and the inventors of MySQL are Swedish.)

`FULLTEXT` with `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` is probably not the right approach for this application.  It works on words, not chunks of letters. So it probably won't give you anything until your user has typed a whole word, and not a [stop word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). And, it is a little squirrely when you search a table with only a few rows.  So, that might be a problem if you're just getting started.

It does order the results by the closeness of the match, so the most likely hit is the first one. So, if you know you have a phrase to search, it's good.

For your progressive-search application you may want to use one of these two [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) queries.

```
SELECT title FROM tbl WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('$searchedword', '%') /*insecure*/
```

or this one which is much slower but finds your partial match anywhere in the title, not just at the beginning.

```
SELECT title FROM tbl WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', '$searchedword', '%') /*insecure*/
```

Avoid running these queries until you have gathered at least a few letters from your user, otherwise you'll get absurdly many results.

In these cases say `SELECT title` not `SELECT *`, and create an ordinary index on the `title` column. That way MySQL can satisfy the whole query from the index, which will make it much faster.

And, use MySQL's `WHERE` functionality to do the matching. Don't fetch the whole table from MySQL and search it in your php program.

And, use prepared statements. Because cybercreeps.

Comment: Thank you very much for such explaining! And yes, I run the query only if the field contains at least 3 characters. Just one question, do I need CONCAT there? It just adds together the expressions, but it works fine also with LIKE '%$searchedword%'. And for sure, I will try to do something with security, not just escaping.

Comment: I suggested `CONCAT()` because it lends itself nicely to accepting the search term in a prepared (secure) statement. You certainly don't need to use it.